# How do I add data from a python program to Markdown?

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown

I want to be able to get a multi-line string from a python file and display it in Markdown, so that I don't have to keep updating the Markdown file to match with the file.
I'm new to using Markdown, so I don't have much experience with it.

I tried 2 things:

````
```{python}  
import mymodule  
print(mymodule.mystring)  
```
````

and

````
```python  
import mymodule  
print(mymodule.mystring)  
```
````

I want it to just show the data that `mystring` represents, but instead it just displays the python code itself.

Note that mymodule is another file in the same folder, and mystring is a multi-line string in that file.

Comment: How do you render the markdown file / what tool do you use to display the markdown? This is not possible if you're using markdown on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown itself is a formatting tool and doesn't run code.

```` ```python ```` only helps syntax highlight a python code block.

If you want to add data from a python program, you'll need to use an additional tool to run the python!

---

One option is to create your markdown file with python code. You could do something like this in a `generate_markdown.py` file:

```py
import mymodule  
mystring = mymodule.mystring

# write code here to generate your markdown file using mystring
```

`Jinja` is a cool tool for this purpose and it's available as the python package [Jinja2](https://pypi.org/project/Jinja2/).

Starting with a markdown template file like `example.md.j2`:

```
Hello {{ data.mystring }}
```

You can pass this file into `Jinja` with `mystring` and it will produce `example.md`:

```
Hello World
```

if `mystring` contained the text "World".

Honestly, I remember it taking a bit for me to learn Jinja back when I used it for a project. You can start at [thier site](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) and there is also a command line tool as a python package called [jinja-cli](https://pypi.org/project/jinja-cli/) which is a nice way to get introduced to the tool before you start writing the python that generates your document.

For your usecase, you may skip Jinja all together and do a find and replace in a template file on a placeholder like `{{ data.mystring }}` (or anything else like `MY_PLACEHOLDER`) to produce your final markdown file. Jinja has more features that you may find useful, but you can also go for something custom and simple if that fits your needs!

---

A different approach if you want to keep your code inside of your markdown document is to use something like [Pweave](https://mpastell.com/pweave/usage.html?highlight=markdown#markdown) to generate html containing the output of your ```` ```python ```` code blocks.

As far as I can tell, Pweave generates html *from* markdown and so if you need your output to be a markdown file (like the `README.md` of a GitHub repository), this might not be the tool for you. It does seem really neat though with the ability for visualizations generated from python code.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) doesn't support what you're trying to do.

But in [MyST Markdown](https://mystmd.org/), you can build [Inline Expressions](https://mystmd.org/guide/interactive-notebooks) with the [`{eval}`](https://mystmd.org/guide/quickstart-jupyter-lab-myst#inline-expressions) directive :

In `mymodule.py` :

```
mystring = """StackOverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/"""
```

In Jupterlab (*after installing [this](https://github.com/executablebooks/jupyterlab-myst) extension*) :

```
# first cell (code)
import mymodule

# second cell (markdown)
{eval}`mymodule.mystring`
```

*NB : The break lines don't render since the printed string is considered as plain text*

[image]

You have another option with [Jupyter Book](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/intro.html#) which has a [`{code-cell}`](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/reference/cheatsheet.html#executable-code) directive (*read more [here](https://github.com/executablebooks)*).